# How to split and convert to pascal case oracle column names?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to selec column names and convert to pascal case. My column names are like this:

- IMG_SAR_NAME
- INT_AKT_DESC

I want to split "_" names and convert to:

- ImgSarName
- IntAktDesc

I can get column names with sql

```
Select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_COL_COMMENTS WHERE TABLE_NAME="MY_TABLE;
```

But can not convert to pascalcase.

Comment: is always underscore the separator ?

Comment: `select img_sar_name "ImgSarName" from my_table` will present the column with an aliased name of your choosing.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? You may assign aliases you wish via `select col_name as ColName`, but in Oracle identifiers have no case unless they are not quoted. But if you quote them, you'll have another pain: from that time you'll have to *always* quote them and hope you'll have no team member who will put Cyrillic O instead of Latin O in quoted name. Do not play with identifier's case, implement this logic at the app side (where actual display is done)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if always the underscore is the separator, but if it is, you can do this:

```
SQL> select replace(initcap('IMG_SAR_NAME'),'_','') from dual ;

REPLACE(IN
----------
ImgSarName

SQL>
```

> The Oracle INITCAP() function sets the first letter of each word in
> uppercase, all other letters in lowercase. Words are delimited by
> white space or characters that are not alphanumeric. A string whose
> first character in each word will be converted to uppercase and the
> rest characters will be converted to lowercase.